# double for loop, store every single value, using R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I want to use double for loop to set up a matrix with 6 columns and 2^6=64 rows.  For each row, I am trying to store every single value from S1 to S6. and then find the average of them.  After that, run the out loop for all 64 rows.  I can do it in a very complicated way as following.

```
w <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),6))
for(i in 1:dim(w)[1])
{
  S0<-20
  u <- 1.1
  d <- .92
  S1 <- S0*u^w[i,1]*d^(1-w[i,1])
  S2 <- S0*u^w[i,2]*d^(1-w[i,2])
  S3 <- S0*u^w[i,3]*d^(1-w[i,3])
  S4 <- S0*u^w[i,4]*d^(1-w[i,4])
  S5 <- S0*u^w[i,5]*d^(1-w[i,5])
  S6 <- S0*u^w[i,6]*d^(1-w[i,6])
  a <- c(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6)
  mean <- (S0+S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6)/7
}
```

Could anyone help me with the inner loop. what I am thinking is to use a inner for loop such as :

```
for(j in 1:dim(w)[2])  
{
  S <- S0*u^w[i,j]*d^(1-w[i,j])
  sum <- S0+S
  mean <- sum/7
}
```

This is definitely wrong since S is only replaced by the next value and only stored for the terminal. Even though I have S1 to S6 running out, I didn't store it. It would be great if these values can store in a matrix. THANK YOU!

Comment: Is `a<-S0*u^w*d^(1-w)` what you are looking for? In R, operations are vectorized. If you want the means of each row, you can just try `rowMeans(a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` to execute a function on each row very easily:

```
S0 <- 20
u <- 1.1
d <- .92

means <- apply(w, 1, function (x) {
  sum(S0,S0*u^x * d^(1-x))/7
})
means
# [1] 18.62857 19.14286 19.14286 19.65714 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143
# [13] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571
# [25] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143
# [37] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
# [49] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
# [61] 20.68571 21.20000 21.20000 21.71429
```

But if you wish to stick with the loop, then you need to specify an object to store the output OUTSIDE the loops and then assign values in the respective positions of the vector. Also as mentioned by @nicola you don't need a second loop given that operations in R are vectorized:

```
means <- vector(length=dim(w)[1])

for(i in 1:dim(w)[1]) {
    S <- S0*u^w[i,]*d^(1-w[i,])
    means2[i] <- (sum(S)+S0)/7
}
means2
# [1] 18.62857 19.14286 19.14286 19.65714 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143
# [13] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571
# [25] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143
# [37] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
# [49] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
# [61] 20.68571 21.20000 21.20000 21.71429
```

Answer (score 0):

Or as @nicola suggested in the comments, this could be done without any loops

```
a<- S0*u^w*d^(1-w)
rowMeans(cbind(S0, a))
#[1] 18.62857 19.14286 19.14286 19.65714 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143
#[9] 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571
#[17] 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571
#[25] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
#[33] 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571
#[41] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
#[49] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
#[57] 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000 20.68571 21.20000 21.20000 21.71429
```

Or

```
res <- (rowSums(a)+S0)/7 
res
# [1] 18.62857 19.14286 19.14286 19.65714 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143
# [9] 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571
# [17] 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571
# [25] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
# [33] 19.14286 19.65714 19.65714 20.17143 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571
# [41] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
# [49] 19.65714 20.17143 20.17143 20.68571 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000
# [57] 20.17143 20.68571 20.68571 21.20000 20.68571 21.20000 21.20000 21.71429
```

#### data

```
w <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),6))
S0 <- 20
u <- 1.1
d <- .92
```